# Trying to use USDA Farmers' Market API in a Flutter project

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, usda-fooddata-central-api

I'm trying to use a USDA API for farmers markets in a Flutter project. Here's the API instructions. https://www.usdalocalfoodportal.com/fe/datasharing/

I'm basically following this guidance to build the Flutter app and get the USDA API.

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Any advice? Just can't seem to get it working. The basic scaffold works but it throws the exception error on the app simulator screen.

Comment: can you add the error you are getting?

Comment: No error, per se. It still builds. It’s just not reaching out to the API. I feel like I need to add a search bar and connect the API to the search. I’m also unfamiliar with using JSON, so might be missing something big.